# How to configure thread pool using python scripts

Tags: websphere

I want to configur maximum size of Default thread pool in WAS7 (WAS Admin console > Server > Server Types > WebsphereApplicationServer > server_name > ThreadPools > maximum size of Default) through python scripts. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

`AdminServerManagement` (Part of the Jython script library) got a `configureThreadPool` method which simplifies things.

It creates or modified a ThreadPool according to the arguments you provide.

You can see its implementation and some documentation in `AdminServerManagement.py` located at `{WAS_HOME}/scriptLibraries/servers/V70`

Comment: Thanks Aviram for such a fast reply. When i am writing AdminServerManagement "dot" (AdminServerManagement.) in RSA, I am not getting prepopulted methods option. Nothing is coimng when i press "." after AdminServerManagement. Till now i was using AdminTask, so if i want to use any method of AdminTask, afer just writing AdminTask"."somthing, list of methods get prepopulate automatically. Could you please suggest me what i am missing here?

Comment: RSA will not autocomplete this but it will work when you run in wsadmin

Comment: Hi Aviram. I am  getting following error 

Exception Traceback:  <traceback object at 1400525690>
(<class exceptions.NameError at 1590976212>, <exceptions.NameError instance at 1402164115>, <traceback object at 1400525690>)

In my python file to configure thread pool i am using: 

AdminServerManagement.configureThreadPool("+nodeName+" ,"+serverName+","+parentType+" ,"+threadPoolName+" ,"+maximumSize+","+minimumSize+","+inactivityTimeout+")

and above vaules I am getting from property file.
Could you please help me on this.

Comment: The +xxxx+ are placeholder you search and replace ? I'm having troubles understanding how you invoke this

Comment: What i am trying to do over here is I am having values of nodeName, serverName etc in my properties file. So through one WASMain.py file i am taking those values and passing as a parameter to call method configureThreadPool(nodeName, serverName, etc). And in thid method i am trying AdminServerManagement.configureThreadPool(['-nodeName' , nodeName , '-serverName' , serverName and other arguments). I think the problem is with the arguments i am using while AdminServerManagement.configureThreadPool(). Is there is any prob with the way i am passing these value in configureThreadPool?

Comment: You should pass arguments one by one not in a list (the method expects 7 arguments)